LateinitializationError: Field 'scrollController' has not been initialised
I am trying to redirect from homepage when the icon user it's pressed to his own profile page  but I receive the error: 'LateinitializationError: Field 'scrollController' has not been initialised.' what I should change to the code to make it work. I added scrollController in the UserPage and UserProfile
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  late ScrollController scrollController;

  UserPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<UserPage> createState() => UserProfile();
}

class UserProfile extends State<UserPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isFileImage = false;
  late User user;
  late ScrollController scrollController;
  late File pickedFile;
  String? userImage;
  String? address;
  String? precise_address;
  String? userName;
  String? facebookUrl;
  String? instagramUrl;
  String? tikTokUrl;

  TextEditingController facebookController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController instagramController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController tiktokController = TextEditingController();
  late String userId;
  Random randomGenerator = Random();

  String? searchString;
  String? country;

  QuerySnapshot? querySnapshot;
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map>>? stream;
  TabController? tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    );
    tabController?.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    initUser();
  }

  final Algolia _algoliaApp = AlgoliaApplication.algolia;

  String? serviveProvideId;
  Future<List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot>> _operation(String input) async {
    AlgoliaQuery query = _algoliaApp.instance.index("users").search(input);
    AlgoliaQuerySnapshot querySnap = await query.getObjects();
    List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot> results = querySnap.hits;
    return results;
  }

  initUser() async {
    user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    userId = user.uid;
    logger.e("user id at init user =$userId");
    getSocialData();
    getData();
  }

  final TextEditingController _userNameController = TextEditingController();

  late File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
      Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
      Uint8List imageData = _image.readAsBytesSync();
      storageReference
          .child("Users Profile")
          .child(userId)
          .putData(imageData)
          .then((uploadTask) async {
        var dowurl = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
        String url = dowurl.toString();

        Map<String, dynamic> urlNull = {
          'avatarUrl': url,
        };
        DocumentReference prereference =
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(userId);

        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
          transaction.update(prereference, urlNull);
        });
      });
    }
  }

  // Future<void> _createDynamicLink(bool short) async {
  //   setState(() {
  //     _isCreatingLink = true;
  //   });

  //   final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
  //     uriPrefix: 'https://cx4k7.app.goo.gl',
  //     link: Uri.parse('https://tariffo.page.link/homepage'),
  //     androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
  //       packageName: 'com.svapps.tariffo',
  //       minimumVersion: 0,
  //     ),
  //     dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
  //       shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.short,
  //     ),
  //     iosParameters: IosParameters(
  //       bundleId: 'com.google.FirebaseCppDynamicLinksTestApp.dev',
  //       minimumVersion: '0',
  //     ),
  //   );

  //   Uri url;
  //   if (short) {
  //     final ShortDynamicLink shortLink = await parameters.buildShortLink();
  //     url = shortLink.shortUrl;
  //   } else {
  //     url = await parameters.buildUrl();
  //   }

  //   setState(() {
  //     _linkMessage = url.toString();
  //     _isCreatingLink = false;
  //   });
  // }

  Future<void> displayPrediction(Prediction p, BuildContext context) async {
    var placeId = p.placeId;
    var address = await FlGeocoder(Constants.googlePlaceKey)
        .findAddressesFromPlaceId(placeId!);
    setState(() {
      searchString = p.description!;
    });
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(userId).update({
      "precise_location": searchString,
    });
    country = address.first.country!.longName;
  }

  var addresses;
  var first;
  double lat = 0.0;
  double long = 0.0;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void viewReview(var ratings, String name, String review, String avatarUrl) {
      showGeneralDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        transitionDuration: const Duration(
          milliseconds: 400,
        ), // how long it takes to popup dialog after button click
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
          // your widget implementation
          return Container(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              body: SafeArea(
                // top: false,
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    // color: Colors.white,
                    // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
                    // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                    child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          // width: 200,
                          // margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          //     top: 8, bottom: 8, right: 12),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12, bottom: 0),
                          //     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(11),
                          // width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                          //         .size
                          //         .width -
                          //     140,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                                    blurRadius: 2,
                                    spreadRadius: 1)
                              ],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundImage: const AssetImage(
                                        'assets/images/profilepic.png'),
                                    child: Image.network(avatarUrl),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 8),
                                  Text(name,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  const SizedBox(width: 50),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      _buildRatingStars(ratings),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              // Row(
                              //   children: [
                              //     _buildRatingStars(snapshot
                              //         .data
                              //         .docs[index]
                              //         .data["rating"]),
                              //   ],
                              // ),
                              // Text(
                              //     snapshot
                              //         .data
                              //         .docs[index]
                              //         .data["text"],
                              //     overflow:
                              //         TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              //     textScaleFactor: 1.1),
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 140,
                                child: Text(
                                  review,
                                  textScaleFactor: 1.1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                },
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Close',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }


Initialise scrollController in initState like
scrollController = widget.scrollController;

still gaves me same error

The error is occurred because you forget to initialize the because scrollController object in the initState method.
  @override
  void initState() {
    // add this line of code
    scrollController = ScrollController();

    tabController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
    );
    tabController?.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    initUser();
  }


still gaves me same error

@sanda17 Did you do a hot restart or just a hot reload?

I have done both
